# Google maps to show locations

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

In  my application i want to show two or more points in the google maps and also need to draw a line between them. I want this to show by a  tag of html. How can i do it??

Comment: I can able to display maps using coordinates(latitude and longitude) using url http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=16.968795,82.244475&zoom=10&size=400x300&sensor=false and i used in image tag also

Comment: This question just makes no sense. Show a line by a tag of html?

Comment: <img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=16.968795,82.244475&zoom=10&size=400x300&sensor=false" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need to use the [static maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).

Here's an example with markers and a polyline:

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?
size=500x300
&amp;sensor=false
&amp;markers=color:green|label:1|51.511333,-0.119355
&amp;markers=color:blue|label:2|51.507801,-0.107569
&amp;markers=color:red|label:3|51.510999,-0.104297
&amp;path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:5|51.511333,-0.119355|51.506205,-0.114462|51.507774,-0.10861|51.507801,-0.107569|51.5071,-0.107344|51.507207,-0.105016|51.507507,-0.104404|51.510999,-0.104297">
```

[image]

The last line starts off setting the attributes for the polyline, i.e. its color is red (ff0000). The last 'ff' indicates it's 100% solid, but you can vary these last two characters anywhere between 00 - FF (base 16) to go between 0 - 100% opacity (or if you leave those last two characters off entirely, it'll default to 50% opacity).  It has a weight (thickness) of 5.
After that, it's just a list of coordinates for the polyline, each one separated by a `|`

Check the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Paths

Comment: Thank you very much.. But one more doubt, even i specified six points the following url showing only 3 points ??

Comment: <img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=700x700&amp;sensor=false
&amp;markers=color:green|label:1|16.968572,82.245361
&amp;markers=color:blue|label:2|16.971479,82.235842
&amp;markers=color:blue|label:3|16.966666,82.228203
&amp:markers=color:blue|label:4|16.982346,82.242708
&amp:markers=color:blue|label:5|16.971838,82.23361
&amp:markers=color:blue|label:6|16.998352,82.256527
&amp;path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:5|16.968572,82.245361|16.971479,82.235842|16.966666,82.228203|16.982346,82.242708|16.971838,82.23361|16.998352,82.256527">